"A pebble of disappointment plummets the length of him"
(From A Terrible Kindness by Jo Browning Wroe, Part II Cambridge Choir, chapter 14)

'Where are we going?'
'Song room,' says Martin
'Not the chapel?'
'Choristers go there for evening practice and then evensong, but it's here in the morning.' It's a small, very ordinary room, with cream walls and rows of benches. 'Probationers sit over there.' Martin points to the far corner and gently presses his back.
Even though William knows he'll eventually become a chorister, a pebble of disappointment plummets the length of him.

I take the bold phrase to mean "he is overwhelmed by disappointment". I don't think it's an idiomatic phrase - I can't find any corresponding idiom. Is the phrase derived from a common expression or idea?

This is poetic, not idiomatic. Imagine your feelings of disappointment. Now pack them together, tighten them, make them a small hard thing. Now drop them from the crown of your head and feel them as they plummet through your entire body. It is quick and hard and small. Does it feel overwhelming?

Yes, I think so because it is running through the whole length of you :).

I interpret it differently, because of its smallness and quickness. I imagine an overwhelming thing as a big thing that crushes you down, not a small thing that passes through you like a ghost. But the point of poetic language is that you get to imagine it and decide for yourself how it feels. Your interpretation is the right one for you.

I think at this point you can assume that any metaphors in this book are bespoke and not idiomatic until proven otherwise. It's probably no easier for us to interpret them than it is for you - harder, even, as we haven't read the book and only have so much context.

Since this is not an idiom (or playing off an idiom AFAIK) it's off-topic.  When discussing the "mechanics" of the language can shed light on a passage, your questions about this novel are on-topic here. But when it's a metaphor, and the meanings of the constituents of the metaphor are known, the discussion would become opinion -- informed and perceptive opinion perhaps, but opinion nonetheless.  So I've voted to close on those grounds.

I’m voting to close this question because it's not really an ELL question.  There is, as you rightly say, nothing idiomatic.  It is figurative language that could be used in French, German, Japanese or isiXhosa

@JamesK: I think the pebble here is only because to drop like a stone is such a standard image in English. Other languages may not make much use of that particular metaphoric usage.

@FumbleFingers - yes, and also one see descriptions of a feeling like a hard, cold (etc) stone inside one, often in the stomach, during times of grief, extreme sadness, hopelessness, great fear, despondency, and so on. A quick Google for "a cold stone in my stomach" produced mainly results from the poorer (clunkier) kind of writing (fanfic, Reddit, etc) which sort of fits, I think.

I put a question about an actual problem I have faced - Its a real problem I've encountered. I'm not asking about opinions but about its meaning - it's not an opinion-based question but a question about its meaning (in context) and whether it it is an idiom or not. I don't ask anybody for or about their opinions, actually! I ask you about meanings and not about opinions. And if you don't like to tell me something about the meanings you can lump it. Isn't it allowed to ask about meanings in this forum? If you think this question is about opinions you are on the wrong track.

I'd like you to tell me something about the meaning of "a pebble of disappointment plummets the length of him", actually!

@philphil - you got your answer, I see.

@ TimR - Since this is not an idiom (or playing off an idiom AFAIK) it's off-topic." - How am I to know if it is an idiom or not? You know it isn't one but I don't. So, what's left is its meaning.

@ Maciej Stachowski - No, I can't, actually! In actual fact, I don't have the language competence to decide or to know whether a wording is an idiom or idiomatic language. I think you can understand that.

@philphil Closing a question isn't an insult to your or your question, it's a statement that this is unlikely to be useful to anyone else in the future. Unless someone is confused by this exact sentence, future language learners won't be helped by it. I think you've gotten an excellent answer that should address all of your issues, as well as some helpful comments, so I think you should be all set on this particular question.

Thank you, but it is said: This question does not appear to be about learning the English language within the scope defined in the help center. - and that is wrong. This question is within the scope defined in the help center. https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

All reasoning comes to nothing, I'm afraid - I've tried but 'tis a losing game.

This is a metaphor and poetic language. You are right that it's not an idiom you will likely see anywhere else.
Most simply, the author means that he is disappointed. However, he is describing the physical feeling of disappointment as it travels throughout William's body. We, as readers, should imagine a small stone - a pebble - being dropped through our bodies as if they weren't there. How would it feel? Probably cold, and strange, and maybe leave a feeling of emptiness. It would fall quickly, because it's a stone, but the hole it leaves would just be a small one, since it's only a pebble. (Which gives the sense that this isn't an overwhelming disappointment, just a regular one.)
This author's choice of metaphor likely alludes to more common idioms such as:

I feel my stomach drop - the sensation when you experience dread, shame, fear, etc. and your stomach feels like you are falling.
I have a sinking feeling - the sensation when you start to realize that something is going wrong and your mood changes from positive to negative.
My stomach feels like it's full of stones/lead - the sensation when your stomach feels heavy and ill, likely because you are anxious or dreading something.

As you can see, feelings of stress, anxiety, embarrassment, etc. are often portrayed by something falling or something heavy. A pebble is a small way of saying the same thing.

@MichaelHarvey: I didn't want to leap to judgment on the basis of a few sentences, but the more I see of this book, the less I think of it! This one looks like a really clumsy attempt to breathe new life into the hackneyed  drop like a stone metaphor.

@ Friendly Racoon - Thank you very much for your detailed answer. I much appreciate your help.
